# When to use accessibilityRole='link' in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

I have an application with drawer navigation that uses buttons to navigate to different screens.
In terms of accessibility, should I use `accessibilityRole='button'` or `accessibilityRole='link'` for the buttons.?

[React Native AccessibilityRole](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilityrole) docs say

> link Used when the element should be treated as a link.

For external links `accessibilityRole='link'` is clearly the best option. But should I use it for internal navigation, too?

Note: I do not use deep links in my application.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Link component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/link/)

> renders a component that can navigate to a screen on press.

The [Button component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button) is a component that performs a certain action if the user presses it. A `Button` could be considered a `Link` if its `onPress` function navigates to a screen, by definition of the `Link` component. The `Link` could be styled to look exactly like a `Button` and vice versa. There would be no difference.

If we refer to general [URL linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) which includes `deep linking`, then we notice that the link functionality needs a UI component as well in order to function. This could be Markdown, the Link component or again the Button.

I personally would use `accessibilityRole='button'` for every UI component that is the actual `Button` component or functions (and 'looks') like a button in my application (`TouchableOpacity`, `Pressable`, ...), since this is what a user whose disability prevents him from noticing needs to know or wants to visualize.  This includes the `Drawer buttons`.

I would use `accessibilityRole='link'` for text which is styled too look like a link (text with some highlighting) and navigates somewhere (this could be a website as well).

In general, I would keep in mind that the user wants to visualize the component. While a button, that navigates to a screen, is technically a link by definition of its functionality, it is not a 'typical link' when speaking of visual appereance (but again, we could style our button exactly like that...).

What is generally more important is the [accessibilityHint](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibility-properties) which

> helps users understand what will happen when they perform an action on the accessibility element when that result is not clear from the accessibility label.

The 'what will happen if I click' is certainly more important than 'what the component looks like'.

Comment: "The 'what will happen if I click' is certainly more important than 'what the component looks like'."

That's a great guideline to make decisions. Thank you for your help.